# Does iptables SNAT work for local subnetwork?

Tags: linux, iptables

This is my network topology：

```
                                                 +------------------+
                                                 |                  |
                                             eth0|                  |                 +-----------------+
                                         +--------+  local host 1   |                 |                 |
                                         |       |                  |             eth0|                 |
                                         |       |                  |       +----------+     vm 1       |
                                         |       +------------------+       |         |                 |
                                         |                                  |         |                 |
                      SNAT               |                                  |         +-----------------+
                                         |                                  |
                +-----------------+      |       +------------------+       |
                |                 |      |       |                  |       |
            eth0|                 |eth1  |   eth0|                  |eth1   |
public ip   +----+    gateway    +----------------+  local host 2  +--------+
                |                 |      |       |                  |       |
                |                 |      |       |                  |       |
                +-----------------+      |       +------------------+       |
                                         |                                  |
                                         |                                  |         +-----------------+
                                         |                                  |         |                 |
                                         |       +------------------+       |     eth0|                 |
                                         |       |                  |       +----------+      vm 2      |
                                         |   eth0|                  |    10.0.1.0/24  |                 |
                                         +--------+  local host 3   |                 |                 |
                                 10.0.0.0/24     |                  |                 +-----------------+
                                                 |                  |
                                                 +------------------+
```

Gateway is a linux host with two nics:

- eth0 is used for internet access, which has a public ip x.x.x.x
- eth1 is used for internal access, which has a internal ip in 10.0.0.1/24

Local hosts are connected to 10.0.0.0/24, with SNAT set properly on gateway, they can access internet.

Local host 2 has two vms, which connected to a virtual network with address 10.0.1.0/24, they can not access internet by SNAT on gateway, although proper routes are added already.

with tcpdumping eth0 on gateway, i found gateway didn't translate source ip for packets from any vm. I don't know why.

I known i can solve the problem by setup SNAT on local host 2 as well. But it's so strange! Why local hosts can access internet by SNAT on gateway, but not any vm can? Did I miss something?

Anyone has idea?

More information:

[gateway]

- iptables rules:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3:228]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:144]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/23 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x
```

- route rules:

```
default via x.x.x.y dev eth0
x.x.x.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src x.x.x.x
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.2 dev eth1
```

[local host2]

- eth0: 10.0.0.2/24
- eth1: 10.0.1.1/24
- no iptables rules
- route rules:

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
10.0.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.1
```

[vm 1]

- eth0: 10.0.1.2/24
- no iptables rules
- route rules:

```
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2
```

vm 1 can ping localhost 1/2/3 gateway, it can even ping gateway by public ip x.x.x.x , however can not access internet.

local host 1/2/3 can access internet through gateway.

Comment: You need to provide more details like your iptables rules and how the VMs are accessing the network (brigde mode, NAT mode, etc).

Comment: Since it looks like it should work, can you provide *all* iptables rules, ie the complete output of `iptables-save -c` on the gateway? Or are there really only *nat* rules? Even if something doesn't appear relevant it could still be in fact relevant. Then same about routes and rules: output of `ip rule`?